# NetSuite Saved Search to find aggregate Missing Pack Records

Tags: sql, netsuite, saved-searches

I want to compare a sales orders' items to our route packing items, I am able to do the individual records, but in order to limit the search how I was hoping I need it to be aggregate? Sorry I'm not familiar with this concept. Something like this is what I had come up with:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT({item} = [custrecord_rfs_ms_salesorder_1.custrecord_rfs_ms_item]) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I apologize if I am completely off base, it made sense when I wrote it lol.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the saved search where you were able to do the individual records.  If you have "too many" results or if it's taking to long to load try the following (separately or together...):

1. Add limiting criteria to the search, and you can also add as filter to allow users to change.  Ex: Date is within "this month" as criteria and Date as filter.
2. Use NS Saved Search native features to aggregate results. Ref Suite Answers [8423](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8423), [20995](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20995), and [8445](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8445).